# How to install multiple yarn packages using `add`?

Tags: yarnpkg

Using `npm install` npm install all the packages in the `package.json`. But it looks like you need to specify each package when using `yarn add` according to https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add.

> yarn add package-name installs the “latest” version of the package.

This can't be correct, can it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just add spaces between packages.
e.g.:

```
yarn add redux react-redux redux-starter-kit
```

If you want a replacement for `npm install` you can use the `yarn` or `yarn install` command.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to install all packages in a `package.json` file, you can just run `yarn` to install all the packages.

Answer (score 2):

**What does `yarn add` do?**

When you are installing new package which is not already installed by any way and there is no entry into `package.json` file for that package, then you need to use `yarn add package_name` command. This command installs that package and simultaneously creates an entry into `package.json` file.

**When to use `yarn` or `yarn install`?**

Whenever you have all the entries into your `package.json` file for all the dependecies of your project, you should go for this command. This installs all the dependencies from `package.json` file as well as updates them if any.

Now coming back to your question, to add multiple packages at a time you just need to specify each package name using `space` like,

```
yarn add package1 package2 package 3 ...
```